# jQuery Mobile icons where do I find them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile for the first time.

I have the following code:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
```

Which I got from [this site](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html#/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html). But it is not changing the icon to the delete icon, just a dark circle with a light circle behind it.

Do I have to download the icons separately?  if yes, where can I find them?

Comment: How have you added jquery to your project? If you're linking to a local resource, you need to download the entire theme. Linking to the CDN version, only needs the js link and the main css link

Comment: Ah!  I downloaded the files localls...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are hosting the CSS style-sheet for jQuery Mobile then you need to also host the images (which are found in the same `.zip` file that the JS and CSS files came in).

The image sprites should be in a directory named `images` which is in the same directory as the jQuery Mobile CSS style-sheet (the style-sheet relatively references the images like this: `background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png);`).

Alternatively if you link to the CDN hosted CSS style-sheet then you don't have to host the images.

Here are the CDN hosted jQuery Mobile 1.0 files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/download/*

Comment: `icons-18-white` is not in download package. What am I missing ?

Comment: With 1.4.5 latest is ios theme removed ? I only see default/dark team now. I'm commenting a post from 2012, forget it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can download the themes from github for example: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile

The files should be in `css/themes/*theme*/images/`